# How to assign on a multitrack file left and right using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I used the following command to create a .mov which contains two mono .wav files (I'm not working with video, just audio)

```
ffmpeg -i left.wav -i right.wav -c copy -map 0:a -map 1:a out1.mov
```

Getting this when I open QuickTime Settings:

[image]

As you can see just Sound Track 1 is enabled and both are assigned as 'Mono' in the Audio Settings.

I would like to enable both channels and assign Sound track 1 channel left and Sound Track 2 channel right.

I have tried -pan and -map_channel but I got the file merged just as a single Stereo track or it didn't run at all.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i left.wav -i right.wav -c copy -map 0:a -map 1:a -filter_complex [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[left];[1:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[right] out1.mov
```

Any idea how to get this?

The info I got comes from:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#Switchstereochannels

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1

[FFMPEG convert audio track to mono and pan full right / left](https://superuser.com/questions/1201751/ffmpeg-convert-audio-track-to-mono-and-pan-full-right-left)

In addition to this I found this question, that made me think of it as an alternative. How would the code be for splitting it in two?

[Splitting one stream 12 channel audio into separate mono channels?](https://superuser.com/questions/964629/splitting-one-stream-12-channel-audio-into-separate-mono-channels?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just half answering my own question:

I finally managed to get this code using as an input an Stereo file

```bash
ffmpeg -i "TESTSTCONFOR_1.wav" 
-filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" 
-map "[left]" 
-map "[right]" 
-vcodec copy 
-c:a pcm_s24le "OutputFile.mov"
```

This code splits the ST file into two separate Sound tracks assigned as left and right channel within the same `.mov` file.

The only problem is it is *NOT* enabling both soundtracks and I can't enabled them manually and save changes. I have created a new question to keep this nice and clear:

[Enabling all sound tracks in a .mov via ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1777188/enabling-all-sound-tracks-in-a-mov-via-ffmpeg)

More info about this issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3622#no1

Thanks!