# Enabling all sound tracks in a .mov via ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, quicktime

I run the following command:

`ffmpeg -i "SToutput.wav" -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]" -map "[right]" -c:a pcm_s24le "OutputFileTEST.mov"`

Which gives a .mov file with two sound tracks panned as left and right. But it just enabled the first soundtrack (left) and it didn't allow me to (even) manually enable and save the right sound track.

[image]

Any idea what to include/modify the code to get all sound tracks enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from the FFmpeg live chat. It's related with a disposition. To enable both tracks just need to include `-disposition:a +default`

The complete code would be `ffmpeg -i "SToutput.wav" -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]" -map "[right]" -c:a pcm_s24le -disposition:a +default "OutputFileTEST.mov"`